# Microsoft Access- launch hyperlink contained in data table via button located on form

Tags: sql, ms-access, hyperlink, vba, ms-access-2010

Using SQL or VBA, what is the code I would need to launch a hyperlink which would go to either the internet or a network location? The form has multiple buttons which would connect 1:1 with the first column in the table. The second column in the table would either have an "http://www.internet.com/databases" or "\network7\HH\forms\hrl\".

Only the admin would have access to the table, and the end-users only have access to the forms. This allows all the users to click on the button and have the website or network location launch automatically, without having the ability to edit the table, which the admin would have.

Within "OnClick", I cannot simply type "FollowHyperlink([http://www.**_____**](http://www._________)) because the location (written in the table) would be changing monthly and the admin would have 0 coding or technical background.

The button would not be opening a table or showing the user what is happening, it would only launch the link and remain on the same screen to allow them to click on another button

Thank you in advance,

JT
so far i have:

```
Dim hyperlink As String

hyperlink = Nz((DLookup("Field2", "sources", "[Field1] = SAP"),"")

If Len(hyperlink) > 0 then 
    FollowHyperlink (hyperlink)
End If
```

Comment: Within `OnClick` can you not query for the value, then pass it into `FollowHyperlink`?

Comment: how would I query for the value within OnClick? @paqogomez 

by using a macro?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you are attempting to display this link in an Access form?  You say you have already connected the form to the table with the data.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I do not need them to see it. I dont need any text boxes or anything to populate on the form, just a button to act as a "go" button and launch it by retrieving the record set in the background and then opening the hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the data out of the table and then open it as a hyperlink. so something like this:

```
Dim rs as recordset
Dim hyperlink as string

set rs = currentdb.openrecordset("Table")
    rs.movefirst
    hyperlink = rs![RelevantColumn]
rs.close
set rs = nothing

FollowHyperlink(hyperlink)
```

-----------------------------------EDIT

We found the final solution in the comments:

```
Private Sub Criteria_Click() 
anything3 = DLookup("TargetField", "sources", "[CriteriaField] = 'Criteria'")
FollowHyperlink anything3
End Sub
```

Comment: Dlookup would be a lot more concise way to do this.

Comment: Valid point JohnFx, since it uses less code, in terms of performance however it rarely matters. And VBA accepts this string JT4900, or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I think that using dlookup or SelectWhereFrom would work, but I cannot use gohyperlink or followhyperlink on the selected value. essentially all the dlookup is doing (without a textbox or going to the table) is solving for the answer to the equation, but not doing anything with it. I need a way to launch the previously selected value 
`SELECT LinkLocations AS Expr1 
FROM [TblLinkLocations] 
WHERE ((([TblLinkLocations].LinkName) = SAP` but this only selects the value, I need to the followhyperlink the value selected

Comment: i meant in reference to JohnFx's comment. how to use dlookup in vba, but i realized i was asking a really stupid question

Comment: questions are never stupid, is the problem solved then?
Might it be possible you don't quite grasp the concept of a variable?

Comment: its possible. I realize that where you have hyperlink=rs![relevantcolumn], is how Followhyperlink(hyperlink) is launched, but I cannot determine how to "lookup" that value. for example: ID =2, Field1=SAP, Field2= \\network7\HH\SAP\

where would I add the "SAP" value to your code so that the database knows to select the relevant data in Field2: \\network7\HH\SAP\?

Comment: Ok, so if we take the DLookup function it would look like this:
`hyperlink = DLookup("Field2","table", "[Field1] = SAP")`

Is that what you meant?

Comment: have `hyperlink = DLookup("Field2","table", "[Field1] = SAP")` and `FollowHyperlink (hyperlink)` and it kicks back "runtime error '2471': The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'SAP'"

Comment: @jenZzz, your code worked almost perfectly. | `Private Sub Criteria_Click() anything3 = DLookup("TargetField", "sources", "[CriteriaField] = 'Criteria'") FollowHyperlink anything3 End Sub` if you submit that as an answer, i can mark it as the correct answer/upvote. thank you for your help! one big issue is that access was autoformatting all the hyperlink destinations: "http:// www.google.com/" and "//network7/hh/databases/" as hyperlinks, so when it was trying to follow the path, it was inserting a hyperlink into a text-only formula, breaking VBA syntax and adding characters

Comment: You're right! I forgot the ''. Well, luckily it's solved, glad to be of help.